# How can i use my component method in my vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a method "aggiornaQuantity" in this component that i would use in my vue. How can i do?
Obviously I did various tests without any success

```
Vue.component('todo-item', {
    props: ['todo'],
    template: '...',
    methods: 
   {
     aggiornaQuantity: function() 
      {
       return this.todo.quantity = this.value ;
      }
    }  

var app7 = new Vue
   (
      {
         el: '#app-7',
         data:
         {
            message: '${Message}',
            risultato: true,
            groceryList: [],
            product: '',
            selected: '',
         },
         methods:
         {
           .....
         }
```

Comment: You probably meant to do `===` (or `==`) instead of `=`, the latter is the assignment operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I'm not sure if you want to know how to use the function or why your function doesn't work (as commented above). If it's the former, here's the answer:

---

You have to call it in one of the [lifecycle instances](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html). Most of the time, we call it in `mounted()`.

```js
...
methods: {
  foo () {
    // do something
  },
},
mounted() {
  this.foo();
},
...
```

Comment: my method works, I would like to reutilize it inside my vue,
but I can't use "this." because the method is not seen, as it is external to it